# Name of Azure blob/filename when uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, azure, azure-storage, fine-uploader

When I upload to azure container the filename that is saved is the uuid(guid) how can I change that?

I create the signatur by using the querystring "bloburi" added in the signature request.

```
 $("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderAzure({
        autoUpload : true,
        debug: true,
        validation: {
            itemLimit: 10,
            sizeLimit: 209715200 // 200 mb
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true,
            id: 'ResumeUpload',
            cookiesExpireIn: 7
        },
        extraButtons: {
            folders: true
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true
        },
        request: {                
            endpoint: 'https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/'
        },
        cors: {
            //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
            expected: true,

            //if you want cookies to be sent along with the request
            sendCredentials: true
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: '/sig/'
        },
       uploadSuccess: {
           endpoint: '/success'
       }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs are wrong.
For version 4.4.0 the correct property to set is:`blobProperties`

```
// 'uuid', 'filename', or a function which may be promissory
blobProperties: {
    name: "uuid"
},
```

Comment: right you are.  we'll adjust the docs within the next 24 hours!

Comment: Ok, this has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem. You'll need to pass a Promise to get it to work:

```js
name: function (id) { 
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {   
    resolve("The String You Want to Pass"); 
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the name option is `'uuid'` which will set the filename in Azure to the uuid. You can instead set it to `'filename'` to have the object stored under the filename, or provide a function that will create some other name.

```
blobProperties: {
    name: 'filename'
}
```

From my experience, the best method for generating filenames is to save the filename under a unique id subfolder. This guarantees that you save the original filename, and that there are no naming collisions.

```
blobProperties: {
    name: function(id) {
        var uuid = this.getUuid(id),
            filename = this.getName(id);

        return uuid + '/' + filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, I simply can not get this to work I added the objectProperties but it still set the filename to the uuid, my script looks like this now

Comment: autoUpload: true,
            debug: true,
            objectProperties: {                
                blobName: function (id) {
                    var uuid = this.getUuid(id), filename = this.getName(id);                    
                    return uuid + '/' + filename;
                }
            },

Comment: This should work just fine. Can you update your code above with the changes? Does the Javascript console show the request parameters as sending the result of this function or the UUID? It's essential that you post this information to debug your situation.

Comment: @tdp There were some typos in this answer, please see the edited version, along with the other answer in this thread by Jason.

Comment: I am getting following error with above code - **TypeError: onGetBlobName(...).then is not a function** . It work if I set name:'fileName' but fails when name:function(id){//some code}