# fineuploader server side renaming the file before the put method

Tags: azure, fine-uploader

Just starting to test the FineUploader and I wonder:

When FineUploader uploading files **directly** to a blob container on azure,
I see the files (guid name instead of the original).

Is there any option to set **on the server side** the file name and the full path to save the file ?

Comment: I know you asked for server side, however it can be done client side also. See responses in this SO question [name-of-azure-blob-filename-when-uploading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247244/name-of-azure-blob-filename-when-uploading)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can retrieve the name for any file before it is uploaded from your server via an ajax call and supply it to Fine Uploader Azure by making use of the fact that the [`blobProperties.name` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-azure.html#blobProperties.name) allows for a promissory return value. For example:

```
new qq.azure.FineUploader({
   blobProperties: {
      name: function(fileId) {
         return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            // retrieve file name for this file from your server...
            resolve(filenameFromServer)
         })
      }
   },
   // all other options here...
})
```

The above option will be called by Fine Uploader Azure once per file, just before the first request is sent. This is true of chunked and non-chunked uploads. The value passed into `resolve` will be used as the new file name for the associated file.

Comment: This is execly the missing part (on the asp webapi server). If the file uploading directly to the container. I have 2 methods 1: for the sas and 2: for the success... what is best approch to deal with that direct upload ?

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage Get(string bloburi, string _method)
        {
            var accountAndKey = new StorageCredentials("xxx", "xxx");
            var sas = GetSasForBlob(accountAndKey, bloburi, _method);

            var content = new StringContent(sas);
            return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = content };
        }