# Fine-Uploader blobProperties-Name option is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, fine-uploader

I used the "blobProperties -> name" property for the fine-uploader as stated in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36453417/6746874

It is supposed to set the name for the uploaded file to the result from a function (if a function is set to this property).

So I created a function to get called, which calls a function from an asp.net controller where I create a GUID.

Here is a code example for my javascript code:

```
blobProperties: {//Set the names from the files to a server generated guid
                    name: function (fileId) {
                        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                            // retrieve file name for this file from controller
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "/controller/action",
                                headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
                                success: function (result) {
                                    uploader.setUuid(fileId, result);
                                    resolve(result);
                                },
                                failure: function (error) {
                                    alert("Failure")
                                }
                            });

                        })
                    }
                }
```

It calls the action via ajax, and if successfull it sets the current files uuid and the name to the returned value.

This works great, but only if the file is not chunked.
If the file is chunked, the action gets called multiple times. And for every chunk a new Guid as a filename and uuid is created. So it gets into an invalid state, because when the fine-uploader tries to combine the chunks, azure returns an **error-code**:
**400** 
With the message: **The specified block list is invalid**

My question is is this behaviour intentionally to call it for every chunk? If yes how could I prevent it from getting called multiple times per file?

P.S. In the linked answer is stated that it should only be called once

Comment: You should be filling a bug instead of asking a question on stack overflow. Delete this question and open up an issue in the issue tracker. we can discuss further there

Comment: Thanks @RayNicholus for your response, but I've got no github account to do so